# ¡Es confuso! Los subtítulos

Tags: gramática, expresiones

Ayúdenme, por favor.
¡Ay, chihuahua! Esto es irritante. Estoy tratando de aprender español pero los subtítulos no son correctos. ¡Es confuso! Ayudame, por favor. En esta vieja película de vaqueros, en el minuto 1:05, los subtítulos que aparecen son:

> "lo he perdido todo en una mezcla de propiedades con un pool de ases en la mano frente a...".

Escuchen al hombre. Creo que las palabras en los subtítulos no son correctas. Éstas, ¿deberían ser "una mezcla de póquer"? ¿Qué dice el hombre?

La película en cuestión:

old cowboy movie "I take care of my enemies" 
Scene in question is at about the 1:05 mark
Turn on the CC/ closed captions
https://youtu.be/PfbQPUiGbNw?t=66

¡Gracias por su paciencia amigos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> —Lo he perdido todo en una **mesa de póquer** con un *full* de ases en la mano, frente a un contrario que tenía un trío de sietes. 
> —¿Trío de sietes?¿No le gana el *full*?
> —En ese caso no, eran tres sietes y una pistola.
> —¿Por qué no llamó al *sheriff*? 
> —Porque por desgracia jugaba contra el *sheriff*. 
> —Una estrella de chapa en el pecho no convierte a uno en *sheriff*, y tampoco basta un uniforme para convertirlo a uno en soldado.

El diálogo correcto. Buscá películas que *ya* tengan los subtítulos escritos por alguien, aún hoy es imposible confiar en los subtítulos automáticos de YouTube.

Comment: Y buscá películas con mejor audio. Si te fijás, hasta yo me equivoqué cuando lo escuché a la primera. Estos doblajes son, al menos en mi opinión, terriblemente espantosos. Difícil encontrar a alguien que hable así.

Comment: Siempre hay problemas con subtítulos en muchas programas.  He visto programas en español en Netflix donde un actor ha dicho un cosa, y los subtítulos ha dicho otra (pero aún en español correcto).